# In Angular, Is there a way to do some initial logic before any controller or directive is instantiated but after the app is bootstrapped?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, restangular

I'm developing an Angular single page app by using Restangular and [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). Now i met an issue, i need to call some initial server api to get some global data before any directive or controller is instantiated and after angular is bootstrapped (angular.bootstrap). My app is bootstrapped manually by call angular.bootstrap instead of using ng-app directive.

---

**Updated:**
Thanks @alp and @radim-köhler.

I have tried both the '**resolve**' and the '**run**' method, but it seems that either of them can resolve my issue. I have tried them with following code. My requirement is both the 'hello-world' directive and the 'HomeCtrl' can be blocked or delayed to be instantiated until the resolve1 or resolve2 is resolved, but now the test result is:

1. The resolve2 specified in $stateProvider.state's resolve object only
   can block the instantiation of HomeCtrl, hello-world directive is
   still be instantiated before the resolve2 is resolved.
2. The resolve1
   in the module's 'run' method can **NOT** block any of them (HomeCtrl controller
   or hello-world directive).

I also create this in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fSAaxi6j6Ia0xCrUICL4)

Maybe i need to wrap the hello-wrold directive and the HomeCtrl into another controller and declare an abstract or normal state for the controller, right?

```js
angular.module('app', ['restangular', 'ui.router'])
  .directive('helloWorld', function() {
    console.log('Initialize hello-world directive.');
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        name: '@'
      },
      template: '<span>Hello <strong>{{name}}</strong></span>'
    }
  })
  .controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {
    console.log('Initialize home page.');
    $scope.content = 'This is in HomeCtrl';
  })
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
      url: '/',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl',
      template: '<div class="body">{{content}}</div>',
      resolve: {
        init: function($q) {
          return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function() {
              console.log('Resolving2 ...'); // resolve2
              resolve();
            }, 1000 * 3);
          });
        }
      }
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  })
  .run(function(Restangular, $q) {
    console.log('App module is starting...');
    //console.log(Restangular, $q);
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('Resolving1 ...'); // resolve1
        resolve();
      }, 1000 * 5);
    });
  });

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});
```

```css
.body {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.13/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/restangular/1.4.0/restangular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <hello-world name="World"></hello-world>
  <div ui-view=""></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**The output in console is:**

> App module is starting...
>   Initialize hello-world directive.
>   Resolving2 ...
>   Initialize home page.
>   Resolving1 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make a super state with ui-router

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
    url: '',
    abstract:true,
    resolve: {
            init: function($q) {
                return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        console.log('Resolving ...'); // resolve
                        resolve();
                    }, 1000 * 3);
                });
            }
        },
    template: '<hello-world name="World"></hello-world><div ui-view=""></div>',


    })
     .state('app.home', {
        url: '/',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl',
        template: '<div class="body">{{content}}</div>',

    });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/fUnZ2X7TFBzaRno7GSiq?p=preview

with your expected order :

```
Resolving ...
Initialize hello-world directive.
Initialize home page.
```

Comment: Thanks @micha. It works. I didn't know an abstract state's url can be set as an empty string!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [angular.Module.run](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module) for that matter.

Example:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ...);
app.run(function() {
    // your code
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check the `resolve` setting of the state definition. That would be the best place for any stuff, which is needed to be executed when

- **after** app is configured
- **before** controller is created

*(some cites and snippets from doc:)*

#### [Resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)

> You can use resolve to provide your controller with content or data that is custom to the state. resolve is an optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller.
>
> If any of these dependencies are promises, they will be resolved and converted to a value before the controller is instantiated and the $stateChangeSuccess event is fired.

...

> Examples:
>
> Each of the objects in resolve below must be resolved (via deferred.resolve() if they are a promise) before the controller is instantiated. Notice how each resolve object is injected as a parameter into the controller.

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
    resolve:{

       // Example using function with simple return value.
       // Since it's not a promise, it resolves immediately.
       simpleObj:  function(){
          return {value: 'simple!'};
       },
       ...
```